# understanding auth on smpp node.js

Tags: node.js, authorization, smpp

Ok, I am struggling a bit here. This is what I want to achieve: 
Create and run an smpp server that listens for smpp send requests from our sms service platform. ONLY 
our platform should be able to connect to this server.

On receiving a bind, authorise that it *is* our service, and receive a send request

Only accept send requests from authorised user/password.

On receipt of a send request, send it out to our messaging provider, with registered_delivery = 1

Wait for deliver_sm response to let us know it has arrived

Update our local DB with message delivery status.

My problem - my service seems to let ANYTHING do a submit_sm without authorization.

Here's some rough, ugly test code that I have put together so far. Am I structuring things wrong ? Bear in mind I am very new to both smpp and node.js, so I may be wildly off track.

```
var smpp = require('smpp');
// create listener for incoming connections from our server
var server = smpp.createServer(function(session) {
    // create outbound connection to provider to pass messages on
    var outsession = smpp.connect('smpp.provider.net', 8101);
    outsession.bind_transceiver({
        system_id: 'myaccount',
        password: 'abcdef'
    }, function (pdu){
        console.log("outsession bind completed");
        if (pdu.command_status == 0){
            console.log("outsession bind completed ok, status 0");
         }
     });
    console.log("Srv: starting session.on event handlers");
    session.on('bind_transceiver', function(pdu) {
        // we pause the session to prevent further incoming pdu events,
        // untill we authorize the session with some async operation.
        // auth incoming - can ONLY be our local system so far.
        //if (checkAsyncUserPass(id,pw)){
            // credentials ok
            // how do I remember this for future send request ?
        //} else {
           // report fail
        //}
            console.log("Srv: received bind_transceiver");
            session.send(pdu.response());
            outsession.submit_sm({
                destination_addr: '447957123456',
                registered_delivery: 1,
                short_message: 'Hello from provider, received a bind to server'
            }, function(pdu) {
                if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
                    console.log('srv: sent ok to provider');
                }
            });
            session.send(pdu.response());
        // listen for incoming delivery response messages for previous messages
        outsession.on('deliver_sm_resp',  function(pdu){
            console.log('srv: outsession received a deliver_sm_resp');
        });
        outsession.on('deliver_sm',  function(pdu){
            console.log('srv: outsession received a deliver_sm pdu');
        });
    });
    session.on('unbind', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: received unbind");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
    session.on('submit_sm', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: received submit_sm, pdu:");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
    session.on('submit_sm_resp', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: received submit_sm_resp");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
    session.on('deliver_sm', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: received deliver_sm pdu:");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
    session.on('deliver_sm_resp', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: session received deliver_sm_resp");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
    session.on('enquire_link', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: received enquire_link");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
    session.on('enquire_link_sm', function(pdu){
        console.log("Srv: received enquire_link_sm");
        session.send(pdu.response());
    });
});
function checkAsyncUserPass(id, pw, fn){
    return true;
}

server.listen(8101);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call an asynchronic function that authorizes the user with credentials:

```
session.on('bind_transceiver', function(pdu) {
    // pause the session to prevent further incoming pdu events
    // until we authorize the session with an async operation
    session.pause();
    checkAsyncUserPass(pdu.system_id, pdu.password, function(client){
        if(!client){
            session.send(pdu.response({
                command_status: smpp.ESME_RBINDFAIL //Here reject WRONG clients
            }));
            session.close();
            return;
        }
        // receive SMS...
        session.resume();
        session.on('submit_sm', function(pdu) {
            // do whatever you want to do with received SMS
            // e.g. respond with an uuid response or something:
            session.send(pdu.response({
                message_id: msgid //uuid (you have to generate this)
            });
        });
    }); //End checkAsyncUserPass
}); //End bind_transceiver
```